# Link to an external URL and also run controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get my head around Rails routes/controllers and ajax and I'm in need of a bit of direction to help solve my current challenge...

I'm rendering a list of links from the database, each contains a 'last_visited' field.

As a user, I'd like to click a link and for it to open in a new tab (target = _blank). On doing so the link's 'last_visited' field will be updated with the current time and date.

Here's what I have so far:

View

```
%li.feed
  = link_to(visit_path(:id => feed.id), :method => :put, :target => '_blank') do
    .title=feed.title
```

Route

```
match "/feeds" => "pages#visit_feed", :as => :visit
```

Controller

```
def visit_feed
 @feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
 @feed.update_visit_date!

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to @feed.url }
   format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

The 'last_visited' field update is handled in the model.

While this works, a new tab opens with the link and the last_visited date is updated. The anchor tag is rendered like this (note the href):

```
<a href="/feeds?id=7" data-method="put" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
  // content
</a>
```

I'm using the controller format.html to redirect_to, which is causing (I assume) undesirable behaviour, in that when I "cmd + click" a new tab doesn't open in the background as I stay on the page (sounds trivial but it's a very common and crucial user behaviour for what I'm building).

So in short, I'm keen to hear about an alternative/recommended approach... I've been considering using ajax to update the last_visited field rather than controller/model, is this recommended? How would I go about this?

Any help/thoughts/direction is much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: so you want to update the last_visited then redirect to another page? or update and remain in the same page?

Comment: @Wahtever I want to remain on the same page and also redirect to an external URL in a different tab/window

Comment: @cupcakekid: It's been a long time, but did you solve the problem? I've got the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433915/rails-call-controller-action-with-link-to-an-external-link-and-update-a-join-t?noredirect=1#comment70073981_41433915)