# Rails: Call controller action with link_to an external link (and update a join-table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, join

In my rails app there are posts which has links to other external pages (`@post.link` gives me the link). If the `current_user` clicks on the link, a controller action should be triggered, namely the action `viewed`, which should update my database, more specifically a join-table with the information that the user has viewed the link.

**What I've already done so far:**

In my views/posts/index.html:

```
# Looping through all the posts
<%= link_to post.title, post.link, target: "_blank", controller: "posts", action: "viewed" %>
```

**In my posts_controller.rb**

```
def viewed
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.views.create(user_id: current_user.id)

  #respond_to do |format|
  #  format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
  #  format.js
  #end
end
```

I've created a join table called `views` with the columns `user_id:integer` and `post_id:integer`.

**In my models/view.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post

validates_uniqueness_of :post_id,  scope: :user_id
```

**In my models/user.rb**

```
has_many :views, dependent: :destroy
has_many :viewed_posts, through: :views, source: :post
```

**In my models/post.rb**

```
has_many :views, dependent: :destroy
has_many :viewed_user, through: :views, source: :user
```

**In my routes.rb (I did not change anything or add any new routes)**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations", :sessions => "users/sessions"}
resources :users, only: [:show]
resources :thumbnails, only: [:new]
resources :posts, except: [:show] do
  member do 
    post 'upvote'
    post 'fupvote'
  end
end

authenticated :user do 
  root "posts#index"
end
```

**My problem:**

When I click on the links, my views table is not updated? (E.g. in my rails console `View.find_by(user_id: some_user_which_has_clicked_on_links.id)` or `View.all` gives me nil?

Comment: what return `@post.views.create(user_id: current_user.id)`. Maybe you should use `create!` or test the return value?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in the **link_to** method, you yould use link in second parameter, or Hash with **controller** and **action** keys. But use both seems no have sense

Comment: change it to `@post.views.!create()` and update us with the new error log, most likely there is a validation that fails or your passing a wrong value to the create function

Comment: Thanks for your help :). When I try to use `Post.first.views.create(user_id: User.first.id)` in the console it is working. When I try to use the `create!` method, it is working as well: `Post.last.views.create!(user_id: User.first.id)`. So both methods work in the rails console.

Comment: @Druid: Did you mean `create!()`? However I tried `!create` and it does not give me an error message, when I click on the link. So maybe the error lies in my "link_to" method and my `viewed` action is not triggered at all?

Comment: @djothefou: Oh, so do you think it is not possible to click on an external link (which is opened in a new tab) and call an controller#action simultanously?

Comment: can you put a `puts "I'm here"` to your **viewed** method?

Comment: can you edit your post and add the content of your **routes.rb** file?

Comment: I've included my routes.rb (but I have not add any specific routes, since I thought that it goes to an external link). And when I put `puts "I'm here"` into my **viewed** method, where can I check whether it appears (sorry, I am a Rails newbie).

Comment: You can check it where you started your server using `rails s` @OhDaeSu

Comment: You should add `get 'viewed'` in the `member do` block in **routes.rb**
and try this **link_to**
`<%= link_to post.title, "posts/#{post.id}/viewed", target: "_blank" %>`

Comment: @djothefou: I've changed everything like you've suggested and unfortunately I get: `No route matches [GET] "/posts/578/viewed"`. Regarding my `rails s` output: When I click on the link to an external page, my output in the `rails s` console does not change at all. So I cannot see the **I'm here** puts.

Comment: did you kill you server and restart him?
please give us the ouput of `rake routes`

Comment: @djothefou: I have now tried a workaround with Ajax (see solution above), but I am not really happy with my solution because a) I want to open the external link (e.g. `www.google.com`) in a new browser tab and b) when the user hovers over the link, he - of course - sees `/posts/[:post_id]/view`.

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried a workaround with Ajax:

**My view**

```
<%= link_to(view_post_path(post), :method => :post, :remote => true) do %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

**My routes.rb**

```
resources :posts, except: [:show] do
  member do 
    post 'upvote'
    post 'view'
  end
end
```

**My posts_controller.rb**

```
def view
  @post.views.create(user_id: current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
    #It now renders my external link. Problem: I cannot open it in a new tab. 
    format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{@post.link}';"} 
  end
end
```

**My views/posts/view.js.erb**

```
// Do some javascript magic here
```

**Problems**
I am not really happy with my solution because there are two minor problems which I cannot really figure out:

1. When it renders my link in my controller, the link should open in a
   new tab (e.g. "_blank"), not in the same window. Instead of
   `window.location`I've tried `window.open`, but nothing happens.
2. When a user hovers over a link with his mouse, the browser shows `/posts/[:post_id]/view`. It would be better if it already shows the "real" link - namely `@post.link` - like `www.google.com`.
3. When the user opens the link in a new tab manually, an error occurs, e.g.: No route matches [GET] `"/posts/605/view"`